# Appengine datastore is corrupted, how to reset

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using Go + Google AppEngine, and it seems like I have caused my datastore to become corrupted. I ran a query with `Filter("ContentId !=", val)`, and apparently that is not a supported operation. Moreover, it corrupted my database! When I go to localhost:8000/datastore, I get a long stack trace that ends with:

```
  File "/Users/me/go_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
EventError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!ContentId'
  in "<string>", line 15, column 11:
      - name: !ContentId
              ^
  in "<string>", line 15, column 11:
      - name: !ContentId
```

It looks like it made a tag labeled `!ContentId`.

My question is, how do I reset the datastore to remove this corrupted `dev_appserver.py  --clear_datastore=yes myapp`, but that does not fix it.

Comment: try to uninstall the SDK and reinstall it. If you have your projects saved in the SDK directory, go safely and save your projects in a different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the tag edit your `index.yaml` file in your project root and deploy it again.
`!=` is not in the list of supported [property filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Property_filters) for golang.

If you'd provide your full query and some context we may come up with a good workaround.